# How to delete or replace ´ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I get this string

```
var cadena = "I´m from Mexico"
```

And need replace or delete ´

```
var cadena = "Im from Mexico "
```

Comment: so use a regular expression with replace....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one

```
var cadena = "I´m from Mexico".replace('`', '');
```

To replace all occurrences, use regular expressions:

```
var cadena = "I´m from Mexico".replace(/`/g, '');
```

See the JavaScript String.replace method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace